# Java Generics - Define Method only accepts List or Maps

Tags: java, generics

I have defined a method in Java like below

```
public void processData(Object input) {
if(!(input instanceof List || input instanceof Map)) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Invalid argument type. method accept only Map type or List type");
    }

if(input instanceof List) {
//Do something
} else if(input instanceof Map) {
//Do Something
}
}
```

The above method just works fine.  But is there a way to use `generics` here to show compile time error if user tries calls the method with unexpected argument?  Method that only accepts `List` or `Map` ?  `<T extends Collection>` wont work because Map is not part of Collection.  Is there any other way ?

Comment: You should not write your method this way. It seems to do very different things depending on whether the parameter is a List vs a Map. You should write two methods instead.

Comment: As Java allows two methods to have the same name but different parameter types, there is no reason not to write two methods, as @Sweeper suggests.

Comment: As @Sweeper and @tgdavies mentioned, you can use a mechanic called 'method overloading'. This basically means you can create one method with a `List` as parameter, and one with a `Map` as parameter. Both can have the same name. (With a link if you want to read more about [method overloading](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_methods_overloading.asp))

Comment: How to define a method in interface ? Can we have two methods with same name in Interface ?

Answer (score 3):

The answer is no. The only common super class between Map and List is Object. As others mentioned in the comments, you could simply create two methods, one that accepts a List and another that accepts a Map:

```
public void processData(List input) {
    // Do something
}

public void processData(Map input) {
    // Do Something
}
```

Comment: How to define a method in interface ? Can we have two methods with same name in Interface ? And also user needs to override two methods and one leaves empty

Comment: @user2731629 please consider accepting the answer if you are satisfied ;)